# Surface tension and capillary rise intution

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics, surface-tension, capillary-action

I am high school student I am very confused in "surface tension",

My confusion is that:

1)[image: this image shows my confusion]

In this image I have shown that, In some books the reason for this shape of meniscus is explained in terms of considering cohesion and adhesion forces, but if its true then why do we further consider surface tension force due to solid on liquid surface if we had already considered the adhesion forces, as surface tension is also the result of cohesion and adhesion forces?
2}[image: this image shows my 2nd confusion]
In this image I am asking that, In most books the reason for the shape of meniscus is given that liquids in equilibrium cannot sustain tangential stress , so they will make their surface perpendicular to the net force on the surface, first of all I don't consider it as a logical explanation as liquids cannot think, if they are experiencing a force they should start to flow into the direction of force, but instead of doing this they makes their surface perpendicular to it by going upwards how is that even possible? secondly, if this is the correct explanation then in those scenarios in which the length of the capillary is not high enough so we know in those cases the contact angle changes, but this Net force on the liquid surface in contact with capillary will still remain the same as there is no change in cohesion and adhesion force, so how does the liquid here is sustaining the tangential stress?

please explain it only intuitively because I am a high school student and don't know much of it properly, so it would be very helpful if someone helped me regarding this.